# How do I install Apache Tomcat 7.0.x on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, java

I am a junior-level developer beginning to work on a project that requires me to use Apache 7.0.x, and I'm running Yosemite with a Windows 7 VM. When I did some research on how to get Apache, I discovered that Mac comes with Apache pre-installed. However, it seems that the version is 2.4. Since Apache runs on JRE, it seems to me that I should be able to have Apache 7 so long as I have Java 7, but the version numbers are throwing me off.

Why is the versioning so far off, and what do I need to do to be able to run apache 7 on my Mac? Developing on my Windows VM is an option, but I prefer to keep everything on the Mac side.

EDIT:
It seems that I misunderstood: what I need is [Apache *Tomcat*](http://tomcat.apache.org) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)), which I now embarrassedly know is something different than the [Apache HTTP Server ‘httpd’](https://httpd.apache.org) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)). If I have further issues I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Can you link to Apache 7 The Apache home [page](http://httpd.apache.org) gives 2.4 as the latest. Apace is written in C not Java. I would go to your supervisor and ask for more information as you seem to have totally misunderstood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clearing up my misunderstanding (I needed Apache Tomcat 7, not Apache 7 (which doesn't even exist)), I was able to install Tomcat easily by following [this](https://github.com/gbif/ipt/wiki/TomcatInstallationMacOSX.wiki) walkthrough.

Answer (score 5):

The best option for you will be install package manager [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh) and then run in the terminal:

```
brew install tomcat
```

Comment: `tomcat7` isn't available as a package and `brew install tomcat` just installs version 8. `brew install homebrew/versions/tomcat7` is available but fails when I try it. Looks like the reason is that 7.0.57 has been pulled from the mirrors and the formula hasn't been updated for 7.0.59 although there are multiple pull requests. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/pull/642 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/pull/646 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/pull/649

Answer (score 3):

I prayed to google and it told me that you can install Tomcat 7 under Mountain Lion and Mavericks, but apparently Java does not come with Yosemite.

The answer to my prayers was found at [Installing Tomcat 7.0.x on OS X](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/tomcat7/)

You can also find more answers with [Installing Tomcat 8 on OS X 10.10 Yosemite](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/tomcat8/)

[And I am already flagellating myself over a link only answer]